# java quicksort multiple criteria

Tags: java, quicksort

I would like to use quicksort to sort my objects.
The object named Person contains two fields (firstname and lastname).
`class Person {
    private firstName;
    private lastName;
    //+getter/setter
}`
It should be sorted by last name and if last name are same, then by first name.
So if I have Persons ["Miller","Tom"; "Smith","Jerry", "Miller", "Alex"]
the output must be "Miller", "Alex"; "Miller","Tom", "Smith","Jerry".
Sorting by last name works, but I don't know how to realize the second part.

Here the code snippet:
`public void quicksort (List<Person> records, int left, int right) {
    int index = partition(records, left, right);
    if (left < index - 1) {
        quicksort (records, left, index - 1);
    }
    if (index < right) {
        quicksort (records, index, right);
    }
}`

`public int partition(List<Person> records, int left, int right) {`
 `int i = left, j = right;`
 `Person tmp;`
  `Person pivot = records.get(left);`

```
while (i <= j) {
    while (records.get(i).getLastName().compareTo(pivot.getLastName()) < 0) {
        i++;
    }
    while (records.get(j).getLastName().compareTo(pivot.getLastName()) > 0) {
        j--;
    }
    //TODO: here I need something like if last name same, compare first name
    if (i <= j) {
        // swap elements
        tmp = records.get(i);
        records.set(i, records.get(j));
        records.set(j, tmp);
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}
```

`return i;
}`
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the `compareTo` method for your `Person` class. Compare last name, if they match, then first name:

```
public int compareTo(Person to) {
  int cmp = this.lastName.compareTo(to.lastName);
  if (cmp == 0)
    cmp = this.firstName.compareTo(to.firstName);
  return cmp;
}
```

Then you got:

```
while (records.get(j).compareTo(pivot) > 0) {
```